# Difference between Sample.this.display() and this.display()

Tags: java

Which is preferable Sample.this.display() or this.display()?

```
 class Sample{

 void display(){
  System.out.println("display() called");
 }

 void callDisplay(){
  Sample.this.display();  // 1
  this.display();   // 2
 }

 public static void main(String args[]){      
  Sample s = new Sample();
  s.callDisplay();      
 }
}
```

1. Can You explain the difference?
2. Which is better choice?
3. Is there any special meaning/purpose for Sample.this.display()?

Comment: Take a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708216/use-of-this-keyword-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you could use the classname like `Sample.this.display()` is when you are in an inner class and you want to reference `this` of an enclosing class. In the example provided, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

i would go for 3

```
 void callDisplay(){
  display();  // 3  
 }
```

dont think there is a real difference but all the extra this and Sample.this only add non needed code so i would not use them at all

unlike

```
 private String something;
 void setSomthing(String something){
     this.something = something;
 }
```

where it is absolutely needed

Answer (score 0):

You are calling from same class, you don't need both. Simple display() should be enough.