# Difference between "field" and "this.field" in Java

Tags: java

I'd like to better understand what is the difference in referring to a class field by using this.field and field alone as in

```
this.integerField = 5;
```

and

```
integerField = 5;
```

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708216/use-of-this-keyword-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` keyword refers to the current `object`.
usually we use `this.memberVariable` to diffrentiate between the member and local variables

```
private int x=10;

     public void m1(int x) {
      sysout(this.x)//would print 10 member variable
      sysout(x); //would print 5; local variable
      } 

   public static void main(String..args) {
      new classInst().m1(5);

   }
```

Off from the concrete question,
the use of `this` In `Overloaded constructors`:

we can use this to call overloaded constructor like below:

```
public class ABC {
     public ABC() {
      this("example");to call overloadedconstructor
      sysout("no args cons");
     }
      public ABC(String x){
         sysout("one argscons")
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 4):

The use of `this` keywords lets you disambiguate between member variables and locals, such as function parameters:

```
public MyClass(int integerField) {
    this.integerField = integerField;
}
```

The code snippet above assigns the value of local variable `integerField` to the member variable of the class with the same name.

Some shops adopt coding standards requiring all member accesses to be qualified with `this`. This is valid, but unnecessary; in cases where no collision exists, removing `this` does not change the semantic of your program.

Comment: Does this have any effect when hierarchies and polymorphism is in place?

Comment: @ripkars No, in cases when you have name collisions in the hierarchy, your most specific variable hides the least specific ones.

Answer (score 2):

When you are in an instance method, you may need to specify to which scope you refer a variable from. For example :

```
private int x;

public void method(int x) {
    System.out.println("Method x   : " + x);
    System.out.println("Instance x : " + this.x);
}
```

While, in this example, you have two `x` variables, one is a local method variable and one is a class variable. You may distinguish between the two with `this` to specify it.

Some people always use `this` before using a class variable. While it is not necessary, it may improve code readability.

As for polymorphism, you may refer to the parent class as `super`. For example :

```
class A {
    public int getValue() { return 1; }
}
class B extends A {
    // override A.getValue()
    public int getValue() { return 2; }

    // return 1 from A.getValue()
    // have we not used super, the method would have returned the same as this.getValue()
    public int getParentValue() { return super.getValue(); }   
}
```

Both keywords `this` and `super` depend on the scope from where you are using it; it depends on the instance (object) you are working with at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same. Because you often type `this.xyz` it's a shortcut that means the same thing if there is a field by that name and there isn't a local variable that shadows it.

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on scope. If you also have a local variable or a method argument called `integerField`, then to access the instance variable `integerField`, the `this` must be specified.

Comment: I think I made the edit to my answer at the same time you made that comment!

Comment: that always happens with me and SO!

Answer (score 0):

Though they look and act the same, there is a difference when the same name is shared between a field and a method argument, e.g.:

```
private String name;

public void setName(String name){

    this.name = name;

}
```

`name` is the passed parameter, and `this.name` is the proper class field.
Notice that typing `this.`... prompts you a list of all the class fields [and methods] in many IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.

So, when you call a method within a object the call looks like this:

```
public class MyClass{

    private int field;

    public MyClass(){
        this(10); // Will call the constructor with a int argument
    }

    public MyClass(int value){
    }

    //And within a object, the methods look like this
    public void myMethod(MyClass this){ //A reference of a object of MyClass
        this.field = 10; // The current object field
    }

}
```