# Intent object showing error Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am working with android activities , and trying to launch an activity when a button is clicked on the previous activity, the problem start in intent object, because the first parameter i.e; context parameter of intent constructor doesn't work with "this, MainActivity.this, getApplicationContext(),getBaseContext" i tried all of the parameters in the first parameter of the intent constructor object. Below is my code.

```
package com.example.nadeemahmad.guitest;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button ma_sub_btn,prof_sub_btn;
    RelativeLayout ma_rel_lay2,ma_rel_lay3,ma_dots_ly;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ma_sub_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ma_sub_btn);
        ma_rel_lay2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ma_rel_lay2);
        ma_rel_lay3 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ma_rel_lay3);
        ma_dots_ly = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ma_dots_ly);

        ma_sub_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ma_rel_lay2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ma_rel_lay3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ma_dots_ly.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        prof_sub_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, profile.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }




}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vETV8.png)

Comment: Post the stack trace

Comment: the crash logcat , where you see what happend aka "android monitor" at the bottom of android studio

Comment: You didnt intialize **prof_sub_btn** in your code

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran I did

Comment: Update your code in your question, Now also it's crashing..?

Comment: If still crashing, check your manifest file, that you register **profile** activity

Comment: Check the Image link @A.Edwar

Comment: cant open your image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `NullPointerException` for Button `prof_sub_btn`. The problem is you have not initialized Button `prof_sub_btn` before setting `OnClickListener` to it..

**Try this:**

```
prof_sub_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prof_sub_btn);
prof_sub_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, profile.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: OMG ! Thanks, i didn't do that

Comment: @Kode Gylaxy did you read my comment, I asked you long back did you initialized, anyway you solved your problem (Y).

Comment: @KodeGylaxy Most welcome dear. If my answer seems useful, then i hope you will give an upvote. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks to you too @MuthukrishnanRajendran I was thinking that your are asking for the first line

Answer (score 0):

you have written `this` inside `onClick`... try writting `MainActivity.this` and it should work.. more on using `this` keyword [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8708230/3746306)

`Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, profile.class);`

in your case after watching stacktrace ans should be to bind `prof_sub_btn` button with xml.

Comment: Read the question again dude

Comment: This is what i tried and i mentioned in the question as well, by passing " MainActivity.this, getApplicationContext(),getBaseContext" crashes my app and stop it from running

Comment: `Intent i = new Intent(this, profile.class);` this line would never work since it is inside onClick. all you need to do is  `Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, profile.class);`

Comment: if still not working then please post your stack trace on which line app is terminating

Comment: Check the Image link @NileshDeokar

Comment: what is on line 36 ?

Comment: It is null pointer exception on widget.. `prof_sub_btn` you haven't done binding with xml

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after set content view :

```
prof_sub_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prof_sub_btn);
```